# How to count the number of files in a folder in external storage?

Tags: android

I wanted to know the count of my downloaded files in a folder saved in my external strorage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this,and replace **yourfolder** with your actual folder name

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourfolder");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
   int numberOfFiles = files.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!.. this is the best answer I tried. Love you man! hart hart <3

Comment: @rubberdont,So please accept it,so it may help others

Comment: This will only count the files and not the sub-directories. If you want to know the total number of files in a folder, have a look at my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61404968/5550161

Comment: before get the number of files, files null check will be useful!

Answer (score 2):

```
     File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "New Folder");
int counter = 0;
        for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile())


        {

            String name = f.getName();
    counter++;
                    Log.i("file names", name);


        }
    Log.d("TAG", "File count: " + counter);
        }
```

Try this. I  didn't try this before but it's worth a try. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
int count = file.listFiles().length;
```

where `file` is the path to you folder.

Also if you have other folders in your folder you should do something like

```
int count=0;

for (File  file : file.listFiles())
{
    if(!file.isDirectory())
        count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String folderName = "MyFolder";

File f = new File(baseDir + File.Separator + folderName);

int count = f.listFiles().length
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are sub-directories inside the folders, as shown below:

```
- enquiredFolder
  - image.jpg
  - movie.mp4
  - gif.gif
  - someFolder
    - imageInFolder.jpg
    - movieInFolder.mp4
```

Then the accepted answer will return `4`(because there are 4 files inside the enquired folder), but there are actually 6 files if you count the sub-directories.

---

If you want to know the actual number of files inside a directory, you can do it like this:

```java
public int getNumberOfFiles(File path) {
    int numberOfFiles = 0;
    if(path.exists()) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        if (files == null) {
            return numberOfFiles;
        }
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                numberOfFiles++;
                numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles + getNumberOfFiles(file);
            } else {
                numberOfFiles++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfFiles;
}
```

This will return the total number of files inside of a directory(including the sub-directories).